# Android - Organizing Login fragment and MVC principles

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

By following basic tutorials I've created a login fragment that has a username textview, password textview, and button. It POSTS the login info to an API which validates the login. EVERYTHING i do is in the login fragment (controller).

I have 3 questions:

1. Following Model, View, Controller - I do not have a model. The View is the layout, and the controller is the fragment. Is this right?
2. I feel as if the login code should be broken down into more classes... such as separating out the post request from the rest of the code. If I were to move the asynchronous request to another class file, I would also have to pass the views needing to be hidden while attempting to validate the user. Is there a better way to accomplish this, or is it OK to leave the http request code in the login fragment?
3. Is there something I'm missing that might need to be in another class?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, in Android you don't have typical MVC pattern like in some web applications. You can treat XML layouts as a views. It's provided by design of the Android API. Activity is the actual controller. If you have some complicated logic you can create separate classes, which will be responsible for that logic. Activity shouldn't be of course "God class" holding all the operations. You can store your models in a separate package as a POJO objects and access them via other classes responsible for logic of the application. You shouldn't keep HTTP requests in Activity or Fragment. You should move them to another class to separate logic responsible for displaying data from logic responsible for retrieving data. Fragments should be used only when it's necessary, but not all the time. You can use them, when you want to display dialog, use tabs in your layout or create adaptive layout for tablets and mobile phones. I think, if you don't really need fragments, you don't have to use them. You can read how [Square is advocating against Android Fragments](https://corner.squareup.com/2014/10/advocating-against-android-fragments.html). You can deal with asynchronous requests with RxJava. You can return Observables and subscribe them every time you want to create asynchronous request. It gives you good granulation, separation and control over your code. 
Of course, it's only my opinion based on some experiences and I may be wrong. I'm eager to hear opinion of other developers and their experiences.